# How to create a synchronize block using a @PathVariable in a Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, synchronization

I have the need to create a synchronized block in a Spring MVC controller, in which I want to use a @PathVariable as my synchronizing object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/{providerId}/{contractId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type!=multipart/form-data")
public void uploadChunked(
        @PathVariable final long providerId,
        @PathVariable final Long contractId ) {

    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

    // store the attachment
    synchronized( contractId ){
        contractService.addAttachment( providerId, contractId, attachment );
    }
}
```

I'm auto boxing `contractId` into a `Long` and using it for the synchronize object, however synchronizing on auto boxed values could be an issue if I create another synchronize block elsewhere against an auto boxed Long.  According to the [JLS 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would always yield an
>   identical reference. In practice, this may not be feasible using
>   existing implementation techniques.

Consequently, this block may be waiting for a completely unrelated synchronize block on a boxed Long to complete which is unacceptable.

However, given that the controller is essentially a singleton, how can I safely synchronize against the contractId?  To be clear, only calls to this method with the same `contractId` must be synchronized - calls with different `contractId`s can run concurrently.

I have been unable to find any existing libraries that provide this simple support.  Short of creating my own util lib/class (ex: static concurrent hashmap to store lock objects by `contractId`), is there another cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, you cannot depend on the primitive wrapper types to synchronize around such values. One possible solution is to maintain a `ConcurrentHashMap` where you `putIfAbsent` a new lock object using your `contractId` as a key. If the method returns an object, you lock on that. If it doesn't, you lock on the object you created. You can then clear the entry from the map.

This obviously won't work over many deployments of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; that's pretty much what I had figured as well.  But in order to prevent memory leaks, as you suggested, I have to clear the entry from the map when I am done using it.  Which means I have to track the number of times it is requested as a lock object and returned.  Which itself (tracking the number of times it is borrowed/returned) has to be in a synchronized block.  So basically, managing the semaphore myself.  I am surprised that there isn't already a library out there that already encompasses all this work for you.  But I couldn't find anything in Guava or other.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called XSync - a thread-safe mutex factory, that provide ability to synchronize by the value of the object (not by the object).
And you can use it for all type of objects which you need.

https://github.com/antkorwin/xsync

```
    xSync.execute(contractId, () -> {
           contractService.addAttachment( providerId, contractId, attachment );
    });
```